# Calling a generic function without arguments

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic function `baz` that takes no arguments and want to call it from another member function `helper`. I wanted to specify the type when I called the function. I tried doing `baz<T>()` but this didn't compile. The only way I was able to get it to compile was this way:

```
class Foo<T> {
  public Foo<?> helper() {
    return baz();
  }

  public <R> Foo<R> baz() {
    return new Foo<R>();
  }
}
```

How does this compile? What type is `baz` returning? I come from a C++ background BTW.

Comment: I'm not an expert in C++, but iirc, in C++ a template (which looks syntactically like Java's generics) will build a special class for you for each type you instantiate.  So an <int> type is different from a <Widget> type.  In Java, you get the opposite.  There's only one `Foo` .class file in your program, and it handles all types.  This has some disadvantages but prevents code bloat.  Thus, there's "really" no type here.  It's all just compile time checks to try to help you out with type safety.  If that's not what you're doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: It's essentially returning `Foo<?>`. As mentioned, generics are a compile time feature; generics do not exist at runtime. At runtime, any generic types will be "erased", representing `Object` opposed to whatever type you specified. Your code compiles because there are no type conflicts - the type is inferred, even if that "type" is a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a quick solution to answer your direct question. Here's how you can dictate the type of `R` inside `helper()`:

```
public Foo<?> helper() {
    return this.<String>baz(); //R forced to be String, change to what you want
}
```

Now, there's a side note:

It's strange to have instance methods of a generic type that declare a different type parameter for the same class. Unless your `baz` method clearly indicated the transformation and left control to the caller (as in `stream.map()`), this is probably not what you want to do. Otherwise such patterns are used with static methods (assuming that's justified), where `T` of `Foo` is not applicable.

All that is to say that your code was probably meant to be as below, if `helper()` is meant to transform a `Foo<T>` into some `Foo<R>`:

```
class Foo<T> {
    // converting this Foo<T> to Foo<R>
    // Normally, helper() would take a parameter related to T
    public <U> Foo<U> helper() {
        return Foo.<U>baz();
    }

    // Making a Foo<R>, R is not related to T
    public static <R> Foo<R> baz() {
        return new Foo<R>();
    }
}
```